# /review - Incorrect Page <title>

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, title

Not a huge issue, but I just noticed that the page title for [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) is always `<title>Review New User Posts - Stack Overflow</title>` (except for the ["Suggested Edits"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=day) tab, which has a correct title of "Review Post Edit Suggestions").

The current title (kind of) makes sense for the ["First Answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1) and ["First Questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1) tabs.  I understand the reasoning for calling these "New User Posts" as I'm sure a vast majority of them are from new users, but to play devils advocate, a users first answer/question can come weeks/months/years after they are "new".

The ["Low Quality"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1) and ["Late Answers"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1) tabs, however, contain more seasoned users' posts then new users' posts (I have no proof of these numbers, it just seemed that way during my ~2500 reviews), so those page titles may need some lovin.

My suggestion (if it matters) is to just use the tab name (`<title>Review [tab_name] - Stack Overflow</title>`):

- [Review First Answers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1)
- [Review Low Quality Posts - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1)
- [Review First Questions - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1)
- [Review Late Answers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=all&no-random=1)
- [Review Suggested Edits - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=500&filter=day)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, to be deployed later.

Also fixed the last place we call "Suggested Edits"  - "Edit Suggestions" ... good riddance.